# Place a button after Gridview.count - Flutter

Tags: android-layout, flutter

I have four cards simply  now i want a button in the end and center how would it would be

[image: existing grid view]

Comment: try using floating action button inside scaffold https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

Comment: is that a `persistentFooterButton`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Insert GridView.counter in a Column
2. set shrinkWrap and primary property as true
3. put your button inside Column and below gridview, not inside button.
4. put the button in Center Widget / set crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   class Test extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _TestState createState() => _TestState();
   }

   class _TestState extends State<Test> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("Page - 2"),
         ),
         body: SafeArea(
           child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               GridView.count(
                 shrinkWrap: true,
                 primary: true,
                 crossAxisCount: 2,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Container(
                     color: Colors.red,
                   ),
                   Container(
                     color: Colors.green,
                   ),
                   Container(
                     color: Colors.blue,
                   ),
                   Container(
                     color: Colors.yellow,
                   ),

                 ],
               ),
               Divider(
                 color: Colors.grey.shade600,
               ),
               Center(
                 child: RaisedButton(
                   child: Text("Button"),
                   onPressed: (){},
                 ),
               )
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: if the grid items increase you would need to make it scrollable make sure to put your column in single child ScrollView with physics set to scroll Physics and gridview physics set to never scroll this way the singlechildscroll will be scrollable and not the grid view making the entire screen to scroll